# Continuous border with math markup within code/algorithm markup

Tags: listings, border

I'm currently facing an aesthetic issue. The borders of my code/algorithm section are being divided by in-code math markup:

[image]

Table has been generated with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{listings}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lstset{
numbers=left, 
numberstyle=\small, 
numbersep=8pt, 
frame = single, 
language=Python, 
framexleftmargin=15pt
}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*}{*)}]
if (*$\exists s \in S \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \times \{\text{label } | \text{ label } \in \{0,1\} \}$*) with label 1:
    (*$r = \underset{\text{label(s) = 1} }{\max ||s||}$*)
else:
    (*$r = \underset{\text{label(s) = 0} }{\min ||s||} - 10^{-1000} $*)
return B[0, r]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Anyone knows how can I make the vertical borders be continuous despite the math markup? Or at least remove the vertical borders?

I am working in Overleaf, by the way.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi Edited the question. Plese tell me if I provided enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tcblisting` to generate the frame for you.

Or, to remove vertical borders, simply specify `frame=none`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable, skins}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  listing only,
  sharp corners,
  arc=0mm,
  colback=white,
  boxsep=1mm,
  top=0mm,
  bottom=0mm,
  left=6mm,
  right=1mm,
  listing options={
    numbers=left, 
    numberstyle=\small, 
    numbersep=8pt, 
    language=Python, 
    escapeinside={(*}{*)}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{mylisting}
if (*$\exists s \in S \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \times \{\text{label } | \text{ label } \in \{0,1\} \}$*) with label 1:
    (*$r = \underset{\text{label(s) = 1} }{\max ||s||}$*)
else:
    (*$r = \underset{\text{label(s) = 0} }{\min ||s||} - 10^{-1000} $*)
return B[0, r]
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any way to set the thickness of the border?

Comment: border thickness can be adjusted with `boxrule=1pt` in the declaration of `mylisting`

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in `listings.sty` explained in the documentation under the heading `8.2`

[image]

and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}

\lstset{
numbers=left, 
numberstyle=\small, 
numbersep=2pt, 
%frame = single, 
language=Python, 
framexleftmargin=15pt
}

\begin{verbatimwrite}{temp.c}
if (*$\exists s \in S \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \times \{\text{label } | \text{ label } \in \{0,1\} \}$*) with label 1:
    (*$r = \underset{\text{label(s) = 1} }{\max ||s||}$*)
else:
    (*$r = \underset{\text{label(s) = 0} }{\min ||s||} - 10^{-1000} $*)
return B[0, r]
\end{verbatimwrite}

\begin{mdframed}
\lstinputlisting[escapeinside={(*}{*)}]{./temp.c}
\end{mdframed}


\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Any way to minimize top and bottom margin within the frame?

Comment: It is possible, and you can meet the requirement, with the help of `\begin{mdframed}[innertopmargin=12pt,innerbottommargin=12pt]`